# is SDL2 framework cross platform?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

are there any differences when writing code for SDL2 in mac and windows? if i write a program with SDL2 from linux/mac will it be able to run on other operating systems without any changes needed.

Comment: ***is SDL2 framework cross platform?*** Yes. It works on linux, macOS and windows and other OSs

Comment: ***if i write a program with SDL2 from linux/mac will it be able to run on other operating systems without any changes needed.*** Someone would have to recompile for their target OS. You may want to use CMake or similar for the project file generation.

Comment: Assuming you wrote it correctly, it will work unchanged. But as drescherjm said, you'll need to compile for each OS separately.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SDL2 is multi-platform framework. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer) & [LibSDL webpage](https://www.libsdl.org/)

But remember, your code needs to be corrected per OS if you use OS specific functionality.

Also it's available in many languages, for example:

- Ada
- Beef
- C
- C++
- C#
- D
- Fortran
- Genie
- Go
- Haskell
- Julia
- Lua
- Nim
- OCaml
- Pascal
- Perl (via SDL)
- PHP
- Python (several, e.g. pygame_sdl2 and sdl2hl)